# C# Asynchronous Sockets: Is this thread-safe and correctly done?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I need to implement a TCP client application. The client and the server send messages to each other. I want to make this program scalable enough to handle connections to multiple servers at the same time. It seems like asynchronous sockets is the way to go for this. I'm new to C# so I'm pretty sure I don't know what I'm doing here. I wrote some classes and a simple console program to get started with. Eventually, I want to create a Windows Forms application but I want to start small and simple first. The Client class runs in its own thread. Is this all thread-safe and correctly done? It's a lot of code and I tried to cut out some fat.

Program.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace FastEyeClient
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Client client = new Client();
                client.ConnectEvent += new ConnectEventHandler(OnConnect);
                client.SetLiveStatusEvent += new SetLiveStatusEventHandler(OnSetLiveStatus);

                client.Connect("hostname", 1987);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                client.SetLiveStatus("hostname", true);
            }

            private static void OnConnect(object sender, ConnectEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            private static void OnSetLiveStatus(object sender, SetLiveStatusEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Client.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace FastEyeClient
    {
        public delegate void ConnectEventHandler(object sender, ConnectEventArgs e);
        public delegate void SetLiveStatusEventHandler(object sender, SetLiveStatusEventArgs e);

        public class Client : IDisposable
        {
            public event ConnectEventHandler ConnectEvent;
            public event SetLiveStatusEventHandler SetLiveStatusEvent;

            ServerManager m_Manager;

            EventWaitHandle m_WaitHandle;
            readonly object m_Locker;
            Queue<Event> m_Tasks;
            Thread m_Thread;

            public Client()
            {
                m_Manager = new ServerManager(this);

                m_WaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                m_Locker = new object();
                m_Tasks = new Queue<Event>();

                m_Thread = new Thread(Run);
                m_Thread.Start();
            }

            public void EnqueueTask(Event task)
            {
                lock (m_Locker)
                {
                    m_Tasks.Enqueue(task);
                }

                m_WaitHandle.Set();
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                EnqueueTask(null);
                m_Thread.Join();
                m_WaitHandle.Close();
            }

            private void Run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Event task = null;

                    lock (m_Locker)
                    {
                        if (m_Tasks.Count > 0)
                        {
                            task = m_Tasks.Dequeue();

                            if (task == null)
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (task != null)
                    {
                        task.DoTask(m_Manager);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m_WaitHandle.WaitOne();
                    }
                }
            }

            public void Connect(string hostname, int port)
            {
                EnqueueTask(new ConnectEvent(hostname, port));
            }

            public void SetLiveStatus(string hostname, bool status)
            {
                EnqueueTask(new SetLiveEvent(hostname, status));
            }

            public void OnConnect(bool isConnected, string message)
            {
                if (ConnectEvent != null)
                {
                    ConnectEvent(this, new ConnectEventArgs(isConnected, message));
                }
            }

            public void OnSetLiveStatus(string hostname, string message)
            {
                if (SetLiveStatusEvent != null)
                {
                    SetLiveStatusEvent(this, new SetLiveStatusEventArgs(hostname, message));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Server.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    namespace FastEyeClient
    {
        public class Server
        {
            private ServerManager m_Manager;
            private string m_Hostname;
            private bool m_IsLive;

            private class StateObject
            {
                public Socket AsyncSocket = null;
                public const int BufferSize = 1024;
                public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                public StringBuilder Builder = new StringBuilder();
            }

            public Server(ServerManager manager, Socket socket)
            {
                try
                {
                    m_Manager = manager;

                    IPEndPoint endPoint = (IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint;
                    IPAddress ipAddress = endPoint.Address;
                    IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
                    Hostname = hostEntry.HostName;

                    IsLive = false;

                    StateObject state = new StateObject();
                    state.AsyncSocket = socket;

                    socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }

            public string Hostname
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_Hostname;
                }
                set
                {
                    m_Hostname = value;
                }
            }

            public bool IsLive
            {
                get
                {
                    return m_IsLive;
                }
                set
                {
                    m_IsLive = value;
                }
            }

            private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
            {
                try
                {
                    StateObject state = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
                    Socket socket = state.AsyncSocket;

                    int read = socket.EndReceive(result);

                    if (read > 0)
                    {
                        state.Builder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, read));

                        if (state.Builder.Length > 1)
                        {
                            string messages = state.Builder.ToString();

                            ParseMessages(messages);
                        }
                    }

                    StateObject newState = new StateObject();
                    newState.AsyncSocket = socket;

                    socket.BeginReceive(newState.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), newState);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }

            private void ParseMessages(string messages)
            {
                string[] messagesArray = messages.Split('\n');

                foreach (string message in messagesArray)
                {
                    string[] tokens = message.Split(',');

                    if (tokens[0].Contains("@"))
                    {
                        ParseServerMessage(tokens);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void ParseServerMessage(string[] tokens)
            {
                tokens[0].Remove(0, 1);

                if (tokens[0] == "4")
                {
                    bool status;

                    if (tokens[1] == "0")
                    {
                        status = false;
                        m_Manager.SetLiveStatus(m_Hostname, status);
                    }
                    else if (tokens[1] == "1")
                    {
                        status = true;
                        m_Manager.SetLiveStatus(m_Hostname, status);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ServerManager.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    namespace FastEyeClient
    {
        public class ServerManager
        {
            private Client m_Client;

            private Dictionary<string, Server> m_Servers;
            private object m_Locker;

            public ServerManager(Client client)
            {
                m_Client = client;

                m_Servers = new Dictionary<string, Server>();
                m_Locker = new object();
            }

            public void AddServer(string hostname, int port)
            {
                try
                {
                    IPAddress[] IPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);

                    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                    socket.BeginConnect(IPs, port, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), socket);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    bool isConnected = false;
                    string message = "Could not connect to server.";

                    m_Client.OnConnect(isConnected, message);
                }
            }

            private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                bool isConnected;
                string message;

                try
                {
                    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                    socket.EndConnect(ar);

                    IPEndPoint endPoint = (IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint;
                    IPAddress ipAddress = endPoint.Address;
                    IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
                    string hostname = hostEntry.HostName;

                    lock (m_Servers)
                    {
                        if (m_Servers.ContainsKey(hostname))
                        {
                            isConnected = false;
                            message = "Client is already connected to server";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            m_Servers.Add(hostname, new Server(this, socket));

                            isConnected = true;
                            message = "Successfully connected.";
                        }
                    }

                    m_Client.OnConnect(isConnected, message);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    isConnected = false;
                    message = "Could not connect to server.";

                    m_Client.OnConnect(isConnected, message);
                }
            }

            public void SetLiveStatus(string hostname, bool newStatus)
            {
                string message;

                lock (m_Locker)
                {
                    if (m_Servers.ContainsKey(hostname))
                    {
                        if (m_Servers[hostname].IsLive == newStatus)
                        {
                            message = "Server is already set to this status.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            m_Servers[hostname].IsLive = newStatus;

                            message = "Successfully set new status.";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "Server not found.";
                    }
                }

                m_Client.OnSetLiveStatus(hostname, message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might be more suitable to post at codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not thread safe.

A subscriber can have unsubscribe before between the check and the invocation:

```
if (ConnectEvent != null)
{
    ConnectEvent(this, new ConnectEventArgs(isConnected, message));
}
```

Define the event as:

```
public event ConnectEventHandler ConnectEvent = delegate{};
```

and remove the event to get thread safety.

---

I would reduce the run loop to:

```
private void Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        m_WaitHandle.WaitOne();
        Event task = null;

        lock (m_Locker)
        {
            if (m_Tasks.Count == 0)
                            {
                m_WaitHandle.Reset();
                continue;
            }

            task = m_Tasks.Dequeue();
        }

        task.DoTask(m_Manager);
    }
}
```

1. The loop will continue to run until the event is reset.
2. Make sure that no null items are inserted into the queue instead of checking for null.

Comment: jgauffin, when you say at the end of the first part: "and remove the event to get thread safety." What did you mean by that? I can't remove the event. The Program.cs file would never receive the event?

Answer (score 1):

1. Does it Run?
2. Does it throw an exception(s)?

   Pitfall in trying to run server code in multiple threads:

AVOID attempting to manipulate, read or write a socket in different threads.  Have one thread accept connections from the server socket and spawn a thread to handle transactions.  If you get too many threads going on at once, you're going to have have 1 thread handle several sockets.

Comment: 1. Yes, it works (I didn't post 100% of the code but it's simple stuff like the Event and EventArgs classes). 2. Not yet. And thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the producer-consumer pattern in the `Client` class by using `BlockingCollection` instead of a combination of an `AutoResetEvent` and plain old `Queue`.

The `EnqueueTask` method would look like:

```
public void EnqueueTask(Event task)
{
  m_Queue.Add(task);
}
```

The `Run` method would look like:

```
public void Run()
{
  while (true)
  {
    Event task = m_Queue.Take();
    if (task == null)
    {
      return;
    }
    task.DoTask();
  }
}
```

Comment: BlockingCollection is new though right? I'm developing on an older version of .NET unfortunately.

Comment: Yep, its new. Though there is a backport in the Reactive Extension download for .NET 3.5. There is an implementation of a blocking queue here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/04/12/blocking-queues.aspx that works on all versions.